# to fetch a specific value from resultset in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-el, mule-component

I have a flow that calls a MS SQL stored procedure which returns a value. The output that i get from the DB is {resultset1=[{id=30}]} i would like to store the value of id to flow variable

couldn't find a successful way to do this, Could somebody please help me in this

I'am using mule server 3.4.0 EE

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First place a  `json-to-object-transformer` and then try the following :-

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />
<set-variable variableName="id" value="#[payload.resultset1[0].id]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

Comment: That's strange, the payload is a list of maps after a database query.  You should have been able to accomplish this without the JSON to Object Transformer.